# an question on iterator object in the "for" statement

Tags: java

I am trying to understand a java program, which has a code segment such as

```
for (final Document document : cluster.getDocuments())  {  
    if (documentsShown >= maxNumberOfDocumentsToShow)  {  
        break;  
    }  
    displayDocument(level + 1, document);  
    documentsShown++;  
}
```

Does this mean that `cluster.getDocuments()` must be an iterator object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It needs to be an **iterable** object (i.e. collection or array). Basically,

> It's commonly used to iterate over an
>   array or a Collections class (eg,
>   ArrayList). It can also iterate over
>   anything that implements the
>   Iterable interface (must define
>   iterator() method). Many of the
>   Collections classes (eg, ArrayList)
>   implement Iterable, which makes the
>   for-each loop very useful. You can
>   also implement Iterable for your
>   own data structures.

[Reference](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html)

[All Known Implementing Classes of Iterable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

Comment: What do you mean the iterable object here? How can I make sure it is an iterable object?

Comment: @user if your collection is a subclass or is one of those classes that is how you know.

Comment: Note that arrays are intrinsically "iterable".

Comment: @Eser: I assume this is what you mean, but for clarity: arrays can be used in a for-each loop just like `Iterable`s but are not `Iterable` themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The collection over which you iterate must implement the `Iterable<E>` interface so that the code is internally compiled into

```
Iterator<Document> iterator = cluster.getDocuments().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
 // iteration
}
```

Of course this means that you can provide custom iteration for custom object if you provide that `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily an iterator object, but it needs to be able to be iterated over (array, list, set, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

No, what is nice about java is that all of its collections implement the [Collection interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) so the for-each construct works on collections.  `Cluster.getDocuments()` is most likely some kind of collection.

To use the for-each construct though an object need only implement the [Iterable interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), of which Collection is a subclass.